# how to type in multiple input instances with same name using cypress

Tags: angularjs, cypress

I have to do an end to end testing on angularjs application using cypress.

I have two instances of the same input element. They have the same ng-model, class and name. We have got the unique id which is dynamically generated by the application which cannot be same everytime the page loads or if it's tested on a different machine.

As an example below, there are two input elements with the same name, but I would need the same text to appear on both the input elements. When I use the following commands, cypress is complaining about two instances of the same name. How can I type the same text'Hello world' on both the input elements with same name?

```
cy.get('input[name=description]').type('Hello World')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to try (may not be optimal) is

```js
cy.get('input[name=description]').then(els => {
  [...els].forEach(el => cy.wrap(el).type('Hello World'));
});
```

Some notes,

- Cypress has a `first()` command, so you could do
    `cy.get('input[name=description]').first().type('Hello World');`
  but I there's no command `second()`.
- `[...els]` converts Cypress array to normal array, so you can `forEach()`.

---

### Update - use `eq()` command

<s>If this seems too unweildy, add the following custom command to `\cypress\support\command.js`</s>

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('nth', { prevSubject: 'element' },  (els, index) => {
  return cy.wrap([...els][index]) 
})
```

From comment from Jennifer Shehane, could do this more simply with

```js
cy.get('input[name=description]').eq(0).type('Hello World');
cy.get('input[name=description]').eq(1).type('Hello World');
```

Comment: What you are looking for is the [`.eq()` command](https://on.cypress.io/eq). This does the equivalent of what you created with `.nth()`.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for that info. Also now notice `last()` ref'd on doc page for `first()`. (Could also use a link to `eq()` there).

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#Arguments):

```js
cy.get('ul>li').each(($el, index, $list) => {
  // $el is a wrapped jQuery element
  if ($el.someMethod() === 'something') {
    // wrap this element so we can
    // use cypress commands on it
    cy.wrap($el).click()
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pick any unique identifier of your input. It could be id, placeholder etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question, please check that you are answering... :-)

Comment: Question: `How can I type the same text'Hello world' on both the input elements with same name?`, and answer `You can pick any unique identifier of your input. It could be id, placeholder etc.` What do you think?

Comment: Okay. So here is the scenario which I thought

1. <input name="abc" id="a">
2. <input name="abc"id="b">